# How can I create shortcut for Facebook Messenger's contact?

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, facebook

An elder complain to me that she finds it hard to make calls in Facebook Messenger app (hard to find contact, I guess). Unfortunately, she's using iPhone. In Android I can easily make a shortcut for Messenger's contact like [in this video](https://youtu.be/EHJpc3tbY_w?t=24). But in iPhone, I can't figure out how to do that, am I missing something?

Comment: No such feature as far as i know

Comment: Thank ankiii. Hope they will add it in the future.